# Cannot allocate vector fo size 2511.3 GB

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, cluster-analysis

My data set  has 18 columns and 821000 rows. I am doing cluster Analysis. I received an error when trying to use a distance metric for my data set.

## 1. Definition of the path

```
setwd("C:/Users/Astrid/Documents/Master BWL/Masterarbeit")
```

## 2. Import csv file

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

WKA_ohneJB <- WKA_ohneJB[,c(2,4:12)]
```

## 3. Distance Metric

```
WKA_scal <- scale(WKA_ohneJB)

dist.manh <- get_dist(WKA_scal, method = "manhattan") 

dput(rbind(head(WKA_ohneJB, 10), tail(WKA_ohneJB, 10)))
structure(list(X = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 
821046L, 821047L, 821048L), BASKETS_NZ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
LOGONS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PIS = c(71L, 39L, 50L, 4L, 
13L, 4L, 30L, 65L, 13L, 31L, 111L, 33L, 3L, 46L, 11L, 8L, 
17L, 68L, 65L, 15L), PIS_AP = c(14L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L), 
PIS_DV = c(3L, 19L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 38L, 
8L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_PL = c(0L, 5L, 8L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 6L, 32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), PIS_SDV = c(18L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 0L), PIS_SHOPS = c(3L, 
24L, 13L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 28L, 2L, 11L, 71L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), PIS_SR = c(19L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 23L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 32L, 1L, 
0L), QUANTITY = c(13L, 2L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 17L, 8L), WKA = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), NEW_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EXIST_CUST = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WEB_CUST = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), MOBILE_CUST = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), TABLET_CUST = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
LOGON_CUST_STEP2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 821039L, 821040L, 821041L, 
821042L, 821043L, 821044L, 821045L, 821046L, 821047L, 821048L
), class = "data.frame") 

sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dbscan_1.1-5     factoextra_1.0.6 ggplot2_3.3.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] ggrepel_0.8.1    Rcpp_1.0.1       withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.1 crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_0.8.3     
[7] grid_3.6.3       R6_2.4.0         gtable_0.3.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0        pillar_1.4.3    
[13] rlang_0.4.0      rstudioapi_0.10  tools_3.6.3      glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.2      munsell_0.5.0   
[19] compiler_3.6.3   pkgconfig_2.0.2  colorspace_1.4-1 tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_2.1.3
```

> 

I already tried to raise the memory limit. 
But it doesn't change anything.
Error: Cannot allocate Vector of size 2511.3 Gb

Comment: The size of a distance matrix is the square of the input size. It seems like you are attempting to calculate the distance matrix of 821000 data points (the rows). This would require roughly (821000 * 4) ^ 2 bytes, which is 10 terabytes. Even supercomputers rarely have this amount of RAM available. This fundamentally won’t work: you *cannot* calculate the full distance matrix, it’s completely impossible. You’ll need to approach your problem in a different way.

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph. Thanks for the good advice. Is it possible to use only a sample of my lines for cluster analysis? Do you have a good tip how I can work around the problem instead?

Comment: This depends too much on your actual data, so I can’t give you competent advice here. There may be a way of using random sampling, or stratification, or maybe you can even build sub-clusters first? I am not familiar enough with the field unfortunately, but maybe have a look at the ‘fastcluster’ package, it seems to provide memory-saving methods of clustering observations without building the full distance matrix.

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph. Thank you.